# When to use which Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, software-engineering-se

I've had a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202879/which-style-of-member-access-is-preferable) on coding-style, but I often read in the comments of some questions, that such questions are unwelcome on Stack Overflow even though there is still a [coding-style](/questions/tagged/coding-style) tag. So I searched for a Stack Exchange site which could be right for my question. My question is: could I post my question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @gnat & psubsee2003 great thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just what I do in general before posting a question to any SE site (could be useful)

Before signing into any SE site to ask a particular topic, I do the following:

1. check the tags (as you seem to do)
2. Check the posts on the board with those tags, looking at the topic and what is considered acceptable (upvote, downvote, replies, closures etc)
3. Before joining, I click on "Ask Question" and type in potential variations of the question I have, to see if (a) it is already there and answered, if it isn't, (b) to see if there are similar questions.

It is not foolproof, but it pays to do a bit of investigating as to which questions are acceptable on each SE.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Damien's steps to determining if one should ask a question, we can also look at the "what should I ask" section of the help tab.  Example:
[image: screenshot explaining where to click]

Both of the links circled above give a list of topics that are on-topic and off-topic (respectively).

If we follow those links on Programmers.SE, we find this information:

> Programmers Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who
>   are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about
>   software development. If you have a question about...
>
> - algorithm and data structure concepts
> - design patterns
> - developer testing
> - development methodologies
> - freelancing and business concerns
> - quality assurance
> - software architecture
> - software engineering
> - software licensing